# Se puede pasar $_Post como parámetro de un función en PHP?

Tags: php, post

Tengo un formulario, el cual se ingresa la información y lo que deseo es enviar todos el S_Post como una parámetro de una función ?. lo hago así porque dependiendo de la información así tengo que enviar opción del header entonces me da error si pongo más de un header en el código

Gracias por las sugerencias

Comment: Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: `$_POST` es una variable superglobal... Es decir que es accesible desde cualquier ámbito de tu script... No tiene sentido la pregunta: no es necesario "pasarla" a ningún lado, simplemente la utilizás donde quieras.

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer no es para nada una buena practica. Te recomiendo que armes una mejor arquitectura y segmentes en partes la informacion que contiene $_Post. Esto te salvara de muchos probpemas y dolores de cabeza

Comment: No tienes por qué poner `header` por todas partes. Puedes usar una variable y asignarle los posibles valores según el flujo del programa y al final pones el `header` y los datos que haya en esa variable.

Comment: A ver, lo que deseas es pasar un información por el formulario via post, lo que podrias hacer es crear un input ponerle el valor que quieras y lo ocultas, de esta forma envias la información que desea pero el usuario no se da cuenta, Saludos